# QnA bot published to myself and the group but Cortana not working on iphone and desktop

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, cortana

Deployed QnA bot, added channel, published channel, unable to view from mobile app or desktop. It starts searching web instead of invoking my bot.

Answer (score 0):

If you published to self, this is either 1/ a classic example of *not being logged in.* or 2/ using *ambiguous invocation phrases*.

For 1/ go to your Cortana notebook and make sure that the signed in user account is the same as the account under which you published your skill (to self). If not, click on your account and sign out / in again as that user.

For 2/ watch what the voice recognition interprets the invocation phrase to be.  If you do not see your icon show up (i.e. Cortana is letting you know its mapped the invocation phrase to the skill), try a different phrase when you connect the Cortana channel. Also try using `ask` instead of `open`.  *There is no speech priming in publish to self.* So, for example, an invocation phrase of 'ask toyomatic ...' will be recognized as "ask toy o'matic". Use something generic until you publish to world (like 'ask [my name] demo').

Also, for now, you must use an MSA account to publish a Cortana skill.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If this still doesn't help, send screenshots of your cortana canvas (after you said the invocation phrase), your notebook, and cortana channel configuration to skillsup at microsoft dot com.

Comment: I just reported a production issue re the latest windows update. Saying the invocation will invoke a skill. Typing it will do a web search.  Let me know if this is your issue.

Comment: Creator and publisher is the same user and has MSA account. I also tried invoking using all methods mentioned above. I am invoking from Toronto Canada - I hope this is not an issue. sorry I am new to stackoverflow and couldn't figure out how to attach an image.

Comment: It could be.  You can only invoke third party skills if the region is set to the United States. On a Windows desktop, go to the region and language control panel and set it to the US and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: I changed my iPhone Cortana Language and Region settings from Canada to United States and it worked (Thank you). But I found it's not speaking text - just displaying it. How can I make it speak?

Comment: Try this blog: http://www.octavianit.com/2018/07/get-your-azue-qna-bot-to-speak-with.html